# Android things + (Raspberry Pi 3 emulator & BreadBoard emulator)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, emulation, virtual, android-things

Is it possible to develop for Android things with only emulated item. So an emulator for Raspberry pi3 and a virtual breadboard also any other components necessary ?

Comment: ioT don't have UI to emulate? or what you mean exactly?

Comment: I want to start developing for android things, but i dont want to spend money on any components. Is there any way were i have everything in an emulator ?

Comment: unfortunately no!, android things just supported in android studio 3.0 but with out emulator, i think if there a probability for emulated android things it will take more time. so unfortunately no. no **UI** to emulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Android Things (and, of course, Raspberry Pi 3 with breadboard) emulator yet, and probably emulator will not be created. But if You want to test only UI (or other non hardware specific things) you can use a normal emulator as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427739/6950238) answer of [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell) described:

> in your AndroidManifest.xml add that the Android Things SDK is not
>   required:
>
> ```
>   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" android:required="false"/>
>
>   ... activities etc
> ```
>
> android:required="false" is the key
>
> You just have to make sure, that the code that is running on the
>   emulator is not using any of the Android Things java imports at that
>   time.